# upgrading to ruby 2.1.5p273 on Windows 7 causing problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railsinstaller-windows, ruby-2.1

I have recently uninstalled RailsInstaller and reinstalled the latest version 3.1.0 so I have an updated versoin of Ruby.
So now I have  ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
On a Windows 7 machine
now when I run my rails server locally it starts normally without errors.

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

When I open my browser to localhost:3000 the home page opens without any problem
But I am getting this on the console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:05 +0300
Processing by MainPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered main_pages/_goclick.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered main_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (286.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1220ms (Views: 1220.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.self.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/custom.self.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/main_pages.self.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/messages.self.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/jquery.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/main_pages.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/messages.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/zeroclipboard/asset-path.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/zeroclipboard.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/application.self.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/banner_ad.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:06 +0300
Started GET "/assets/dotted-gray.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:07 +0300
Started GET "/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:07 +0300
Started GET "/assets/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1436912527062" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:07 +0300
Started GET "/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:07 +0300

**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/application.js"):**
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


  Rendered D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (32.0ms)
  Rendered D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
rescues/layout (126.0ms)

Started GET "/assets/favicon16x16.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-15 01:22:08 +0300
```

I am not sure if I was getting this "Routing Error.." before upgrading to Ruby 2.1 from 1.9

The critical new issues is when I submit forms no output on the site and the console shows hundreds of lines, which I will include some below, then it terminates unexpectedly and the rails server stops.

```
.
.
.
 1300 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations/associated.rb
 1301 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb
 1302 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb
 1303 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb
 1304 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb
 1305 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb
 1306 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb
 1307 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb
 1308 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/method_transplanting.rb
 1309 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb
 1310 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb
 1311 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/before_type_cast.rb
 1312 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb
 1313 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb
 1314 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb
 1315 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/dirty.rb
 1316 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb
 1317 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb
 1318 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb
 1319 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb
 1320 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb
 1321 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb
 1322 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb
 1323 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb
 1324 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/aggregations.rb
 1325 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb
 1326 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/no_touching.rb
 1327 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/reflection.rb
 1328 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/serialization.rb
 1329 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb
 1330 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb
 1331 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/serializers/xml_serializer.rb
 1332 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/serialization.rb
 1333 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/store.rb
 1334 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/statement_pool.rb
 1335 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb
 1336 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/savepoints.rb
 1337 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb
 1338 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/runtime_registry.rb
 1339 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/globalid-0.3.5/lib/global_id/identification.rb
 1340 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb
 1341 D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb
 1342 D:/rails_projects/tafqit/app/controllers/counted.rb
 1343 D:/rails_projects/tafqit/app/controllers/tafqit.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Is there any known problem in ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32] with Windows? 
What do you recommend me to do, I am a novice so please bear with me.

Comment: `What do you recommend me to do` - I always recommend same thing: Say bye bye to windows and install some decent OS. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found what the cause of the problem was.
It is old installations of other Ruby versions. Once I deleted them. All is working now.